# Как в Google Sheets сделать регистронезависимую выборку

Tags: запрос, select, google-spreadsheet

Использую запрос, например

```
=query(Book1!A1:R,"select * where R like '%Вступление%'")
```

Но он даёт результат регистрозависимый

Теперь надо сделать выборку всех совпадающих значений независимо от регистра букв.

Каким запросом это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
=query(
{arrayformula(REGEXMATCH(F1:F15;"[Вв][сС][тТ][уУ][пП][лЛ][еЕ][нН][иИ][еЕ]"))
\
G1:G15};"
select *
where Col1 = "&ИСТИНА&" ")
```

Создадим колонку, которая возвращает значение Истина/ложь после проверки столбца, по содержанию которого мы будем фильтровать.
Далее, пользуясь правилом синтаксиса Re2, не очень изящно, но всё же задаем правило проверки строк этого столбца. Символы в квадратных скобках - это возможные символы.
Далее соединяем через '\' полученную колонку и изначальный массив, используя {колонкаTrueFalse\Массив}. Далее обращаемся к этому массиву через query где выводим * или Col1, Col2, Colx столбцов с условием where Col1 = "&ИСТИНА&"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]